# Problem using Autofac library in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dependency-injection, autofac

My code is simple and
I am new to Autofac, I found just one tutorial where autofac is implemented in C#.I tried in .NET Framework and I have this error.

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: serviceType

I don't know where I am making mistake

I am using Entity framework to get the data from SQL.

```
public class ContainerConfig
{
    public static IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(WebApplication11)))
            .Where(t => t.Namespace.Contains("Models"))
            .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));

        return builder.Build();
    }
}


public class AppDbContext : DbContext, IAppDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public interface IAppDbContext
{
    DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblEmployeeDepartmentConnection")]
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
IAppDbContext app;

public EmployeeController()
{
    var container = ContainerConfig.Configure();

    using (var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
    {
        app = scope.Resolve<IAppDbContext>();
    }
}
// GET: Employee
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var emp = app.Employees.ToList();


    return View(emp);
}
```

Comment: which is the row who raises the error? it seems you are passing a null value in a method or constructor.

Comment: Please add information on from where the execption is thrown

Comment: My guess is you have an object that has no interfaces, but only you can figure this out I'm afraid.

Comment: You're initializing the container inside your controller?  That should be done at app startup.

Comment: I'm guessing `t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name)` is returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.As(Type serviceType)` method doesn't eat `null`, and that causes your exception. This code:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(WebApplication11)))
    .Where(t => t.Namespace.Contains("Models"))
    .As(t => t.GetInterfaces().FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == "I" + t.Name));
```

Is problematic. It tries to register all types from the namespaces containing "Models", with the first interface applied to those types that is named like "I" + classname. This has two problems:

- Not all types in that namespace have to implement interfaces
- Not all interfaces have to be applied to types named after the interface (`Foo` can implement `IBar`)

Also, accessing your IoC container in your code is an antipattern. Request the dependencies you need, and let your DI framework handle the rest (are you using Autofac.Mvc?).

To solve the immediate problem, register all types as the interface(s) they implement:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load(nameof(WebApplication11)))
    .Where(t => t.Namespace.Contains("Models"))
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

To solve the rest of the issues, find a better tutorial.